# How to turn string into matrix

Tags: python-3.x, string, matrix

I'd like to turn a string, for example this one:  "1,2,3;2,3,4;3,4,5" into a matrix (list inside list).
I've tried it using the string.split() function but I can't seem to figure it out. For me the main problem is that there are both ; and , that are messing with my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is horrible, but it seems to work:

```py
[ [ item for item in row.split(',') ] for row in "1,2,3;2,3,4;3,4,5".split(';') ]
```

However, I would recommend to write this a as a for loop:

```py
result = []
for row in"1,2,3;2,3,4;3,4,5".split(';'):
  result.append(row.split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following logic will give you a list of list from the given input string.

```
x='1,2,3;2,3,4;3,4,5'
lst= [[int(x) for x in m.split(',')] for m in x.split(';')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If both comma and semicolon are functionally the same, this is much simpler than looping/splitting twice:

```
x = "1,2,3;2,3,4;3,4,5"
result = x.replace(";", ",").split(",")
```

essentially simplify the scenario by making it all commas, then split.